# Use Hybrid API in Azure Service Bus Queues

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Is i possible to use Messaging API to send message to the Queue and Receive using WCF integration (NetMessagingBtinding) and if so how to do it ? what is the service contract ?
Thanks
Offir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh709041.aspx) is a guide on how to do that.